# Access to Office 365 account "on behalf of" through EWS

Tags: c#, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I need help with EWS service. I need to read inbox/sent mails of an account Office 365, the access to this account is "on behalf of" and I usually login with my domain credentials. This is the firt time I need to do this, so searching on Google I found this solution:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ExchangeService _service;
    
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Registering Exchange connection");
    
                    _service = new ExchangeService
                    {
                        Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "pwd", "domain")
                    };
    
                    AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validurl = new AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback((a) => { return true; });
    
                    _service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@mail.com", validurl);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("new ExchangeService failed with error '" + e.Message + "'. Press enter to exit:");
                    return;
                }
    
                // This is the office365 webservice URL
                _service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

When I run this code, the program goes up to the line "*_service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@mail.com", validurl)*;", so it remains as "suspended", no error no timeout.

I don't know what the problem is, can anyone help me?

Thanks everyone

Nick

Comment: Are you an Admin?  VS does automatically start with Admin.  You have to right click VS shortcut and select Run as Admin.  I think your code is using DNS to discover the email server and you need admin.  Outlook uses a proxy server and smtp port number is forwarded to a proxy server where the credentials are verified.  Bad credentials the proxy may just give no response so minimize the changes of hackers attacking your outlook email.   The domain has to also be correct since you company may have multiple outlook servers and each employee is assigned a different server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yes, I have Admin rights on my laptop, but running VS as administrator I have the same problem. The Domain credential are the same as I use when I log in manually.
I forgot to specify that the account is accessible exclusively online, not through Outlook client.

Comment: EDIT: If I try using my personal email the code work without problems, I think the problem is that the account is on "behalf of" but I don't know how solve it :\

Comment: With email, the FROM address of email and the credentials (the account) have to match.

Comment: When I login to the account online, the mail related to the account and my personal user account are different (eg. xxxx@mail.com and my user: yyyyy, both under the same domain of course)

Comment: Then you need a different FROM address in the email.  GMAIL (and other smtp servers) do not want hackers trying to send emails that look like they came from other people.  So the email credentials and FROM address must be from the same account.

Comment: Autodiscover only returns the URL for the EWS endpoint in your code you manually defining that in the last line so you Autodiscover is redundant. If you want to access a Mailbox Folder other then that of the Account credentials you would use the mailbox overload of the FolderId Class.